# return reference to temporary when dereferencing map iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, warnings

Consider this code

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

const int& foo(const std::vector<int>& x,unsigned i) {
    auto it = x.begin();
    std::advance(it,i);
    return *it;
}
```

Both clang and gcc emit no errors/warnings, but this:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

const std::pair<int,int>& bar(const std::map<int,int>& x,unsigned i){
    auto it = x.begin();
    std::advance(it,i);
    return *it;
}
```

compiled with [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/tpVpDj) and using `-Werror` results in :

```
<source>:14:12: error: returning reference to local temporary object [-Werror,-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return *it;
           ^~~
```

and with [gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/xMExme):

```
<source>: In function 'const std::pair<int, int>& bar(const std::map<int, int>&, unsigned int)':
<source>:14:13: error: returning reference to temporary [-Werror=return-local-addr]
     return *it;
             ^~
```

**What makes gcc and clang reject `bar` and why is `foo` fine?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `value_type` of [`std::map<int,int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is not `std::pair<int,int>`, but `std::pair<const int,int>`. Then for `return *it;`, a temporary `std::pair<int,int>` has to be created and returned. (`std::pair<int,int>` could be [converted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) from `std::pair<const int,int>`.) The temporary will be destroyed immediately and left the returned reference dangled.

To sovle the issue you can change the return type to `const std::pair<const int,int>&` or `const std::map<int,int>::value_type &`.

Comment: You meant "a temporary `std::pair<int,int>` has to be created and returned"?